# Intellisens don't detect class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm going to add some Products from a list into the OrderRows table, but when I start typing db. ??? Intellisens don't give med any option to select the OrderRows class and then continue with Add.... What have I done wrong?

```
 var listShoppingCart = Session["ShoppingCart"] as List<Products>; // Cast

        foreach (var item in listShoppingCart)
        {
            var productFromList = new OrderRows
            {
                ProductID = item.ID,
                OrderID = orderId,
                Price = item.Price
            };

            //db. ????
            //db. ?? .Add(productFromList);
            //db.SaveChanges();
```

These are the classes, perhaps there are some error in their relation?

```
    public class Orders
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Orderdate { get; set; }
    public int CustomersID { get; set; } 

    public virtual Customers Customers { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<OrderRows> OrderRows { get; set; }
}

    public class OrderRows
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Orders Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Probably your `DBContext` class misses declaration of `OrdersRows`.

Comment: OK, I know about that, but what file am I looking for?

Comment: Have you any class derived from `DbContext` in your solution? I'm supposing you're using EntityFramework.

Comment: Yes I'm using Entity Framework Code First

Comment: So you need class derived from `DbContext`. Your `db` should be an instance of this class. Can you show its source code?

Comment: In your solution of course. Can't you just search for `DbContext` word in whole solution?

Comment: It was missing in that file and I added it myself. Now Intellisens give me the option to select OrderRows. What could be the reason for Visual Studio don't add this context for OrderRows, but the other ones? Thanks for the help!